Choosing the AWS technology for building a system that performs automated random and stratified sampling on AWS S3 data
Context: I'm building a system that requires pulling up either a random/stratified sample on a dataset stored in either S3/RedShift/Relational database like RDS. The data set size could be in the order of hundred millions of entries.
Question: I came across AWS Data Wrangler that seems to be provide random and stratified sampling (see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/create-random-and-stratified-samples-of-data-with-amazon-sagemaker-data-wrangler/). But the AWS documentation seems to indicate that it requires UI based interaction to set it up. I'm looking for more of an API based interaction for setting up either a scheduled setup for sampling or adhoc (but again triggered through an API, as I'll be building the UI interface to trigger sampling). What's the best and easiest way to go about building this sampling component?
